# How to edit markdown files stored in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, text-editor

It's bizarre but I can't find a good way to edit my markdown files that I store in Google Drive on Android. The problem seems to be twofold -

1. no apps support browsing google drive files
2. google drive doesn't support folder-based offline sync (and syncing file by file is not good enough)

What is a nice, hassle-free to edit my markdown files stored in Google Drive?

Comment: This looks like one for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Chenmunka it's explicitly asking for a how-to, which is not accepted on SR but totally fine here – even if the answer turns out to be a [Markdown editor](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_107) app like [neutriNote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appmindlab.nano) (integrated GDrive *backup* – so not sure if it really fits).